# Как открыть <details> с помощью ссылки?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<a href="#link">Click</a>

<details id="link">
<summary>Text...</summary>
blablabla
</details>
```

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на ссылку добавлялся атрибут open для тега details?

Comment: атрибут или класс?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

написал специально и атрибут и класс, так как сомневаюсь что вам нужен именно атрибут

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a[href='#link']").on("click", function(){
    $("#link").attr("open"); // Attribute
    $("#link[open]").css("display", "block")
    // $("#link").toggleClass("open"); class
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#link">Click</a>

<details id="link">
<summary>Text...</summary>
blablabla
</details>
```

Comment: @igor Спасибо за изменения, но если он представил только `html` - я подозревал, что у него уже готов `css`

Comment: да, Вы правы. +1

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но мне нужно добавление не класса, а именно атрибута, который открывает тег details (open).
В Вашем примере атрибут не добавляется.
Нужно чтобы получилось `<details id="link" open>`

Comment: @BrimBamBo я добавил вам атрибут, если вы хотите, что бы данный атрибут открывал еще, тогда нужно просто строчку дописать)

Comment: @BrimBamBo отредактировал

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('a').on('click', function() {
  const id = $(this).attr('href');
  $(id).attr('open', function(index, attr) {
    return attr == 'open' ? null : 'open';
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#link">Click</a>

<details id="link">
  <summary>Text...</summary>
  blablabla
</details>
```